# How to compare filenames in batch file

Tags: batch-file, compare

There are two filenames: 0_1_en.pdf and GEN 0 GENERAL.html . Last four lines of code is my try (unsuccessful) to compare if the html file in variable %%H complies the rule "GEN 0*.pdf" comprison. Sorry my English, I don't know how to say it better, but I try to compare if the rule gives a valid filename or not. So if there is filename "GEN 0 GENERAL.html" it should show the string GEN 0 GENERAL.html. In case of this does not comply the rule, than no string will be printed. So if I read a filename "GEN 3 SERVICES.html" so nothing will be printed.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
SET "sPDFName=%%~nxP"
echo "!sPDFName:~0,1!"
IF "!sPDFName:~0,1!"=="1" (SET "sPDFName=!sPDFName:~0,1!")
IF "!sPDFName:~0,1!"=="0" (SET "sPDFName=!sPDFName:~0,1!")
SET tempStr="GEN !sPDFName!*.html"
echo !tempStr!
::echo "!sPDFName!"
for /f "delims=" %%H in ('dir /b *.html') do (
CALL SET substring=%%H:~!tempStr!%%
echo K:%substring%
IF "%%substring%%"=="%%H" (echo %%H) ELSE (echo NOT FOUND)
pause ))
```

Gives result:
"0"
"GEN 0*.pdf"
K:
NOT FOUND
Press any key to continue...

Comment: "0"<NEXT LINE HERE>
"GEN 0*.pdf"<NEXT LINE HERE>
K:<NEXT LINE HERE>
NOT FOUND<NEXT LINE HERE>
Press any key to continue ....  Replace <NEXT LINE HERE> for end of of line

Comment: use Double quotation i For `"dir /b *.pdf"`. `"delims="` is not necessary

Comment: One more mistake I have in code. I repair it now. SET tempStr="GEN !sPDFName!*.html" , but still no positive result. Actual problem is that it evaluates the CALL SET expression like the file "GEN 0*.html" would not be found. But it is %%H = "GEN 0 GENERAL.html" that should be found. My idea is quotes. I think the variable !tempStr! probably contain quotes, but I did not success to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main reason your code fails is the `CALL SET substring=%%H:~!tempStr!%%` line doesn't make any sense. I'm not sure what you are attempting there, but I'm pretty sure it is not giving the result you want.

**Attempt 1 (not quite correct)**
I believe I understand what your goal is, and I think your code is much more complicated than it needs to be.

I think you want to test each pdf file to see if there exists a "GEN n GENERAL.html" file, where 'n' matches the 1st character in the pdf file name.

See if this gives the result you are looking for

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExansion
for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
  set "pdfFile=%%F"
  set "htmlFile=GEN !pdfFile:~0,1! GENERAL.html"
  if exist "!htmlFile!" (set result=FOUND) else (set result=NOT FOUND)
  echo testing "!pdfFile!": "!htmlFile!" !result!
)
```

**Attempt 2 (after OP comment)**
I've looked at your CALL SET statement again, and it seems like you are attempting to do a substring operation on a FOR variable

- Problem 1: You cannot perform substring or search and replace on FOR variable expansion
- Problem 2: !tempStr! does not contain the proper syntax for a substring operation

I still don't understand exactly what result you expect with that CALL code, so I don't know how to fix it.

But your comment helps me understand what your overall goal is: For a pdf with 1st character in name = n, you are looking for "GEN n*.html".

If all you need to do is print out the matching html files or print an error message if none found, then this should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExansion
for %%P in (*.pdf) do (
  set "pdfFile=%%P"
  set htmlMask="GEN !pdfFile:~0,1!*.html"
  echo(
  echo Testing "!pdfFile!": Looking for !htmlMask!
  dir /b !htmlMask!
)
```

If you need to do something with each found html file, then this should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExansion
for %%P in (*.pdf) do (
  set "pdfFile=%%P"
  set htmlMask="GEN !pdfFile:~0,1!*.html"
  echo(
  echo Testing "!pdfFile!": Looking for !htmlMask!
  set "found="
  for %%H in (!htmlMask!) do (
    set found=1
    echo "%%H"
    REM do whatever you need to do with the %%P pdf file and %%H html file
  )
  if not defined found echo NOT FOUND
)
```

If you only want to process pdf files that start with 0 or 1, then change the 1st FOR statement as follows:

```
for %%P in (0*.pdf 1*.pdf) do (
```

Comment: The basic structure of my code is all right. I did not mention there are more html files with long filenames. They are 6 but could be more. It would be not effective to use exact filename as you did here:  set "htmlFile=GEN !pdfFile:~0,1! GENERAL.html" because you simply don't know if the file ends with " GENERAL.html" or anything else and longer. I would rather like to compare the variables in loop #2. If the file is found, than the loop #2 can be exited/break and continue loop #1. Your solution would be good, if there would be only one html file. Thanks for help

Comment: And I took my attempt from here: ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html see "Advanced Usage of :~" ... only difference is that I tried to add "GEN 0 *.html" to right side of comparing expression. Maybe I am doing wrong because I need compare, not replace.

Comment: The second code of you (Attempt 2) is really clever. I see this will save the work with breaking loop.